# Are questions related to salesforce certifications allowed? Are we even allowed to answer?

Tags: discussion

I saw [a question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/queries-on-some-adm-201-certification-related-questions) that says please validate the answers for multiple choice questions of Admin certfication exam. Is this ok? Thoughts and comments?

Comment: I don't believe that these are questions from the real exam - they look more like proprofs samples as they ask for reference information (e.g. how many filters can be added to a report) which the real exams don't.  If they did look like real questions, the person posting should be reported to the certification team, as they have breached the test taker agreement by sharing a question.

Comment: Agree with you bob.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If someone has a problem with a question and can show why (with their own research) they disagree with a question I would be happy to help them.

But the question you're referring to was a very blatant *help me with my homework*, which would never get my assistance.

Comment: This is similar to the stance that stackexchange takes on homework questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 5):

If someone asks certification questions here - hmmm - can't really see he has a future.

As for answering - I would treat these as asking for homework assistance - avoid it - and vote to close.

But that's only me.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, unless the asker is looking for clarification or explanation as to why something is the answer.

Comment: Me too, the post that Mohith is referring to was the most blatant I've ever seen. It was 10-15 questions, the OP's answers/guesses and a request for someone to mark them.